# How to submit Ionic application to the App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, ionic-framework

I tried to upload my application to App Store but can't archive my project in the xcode since it is grey out. I don't know what to do since i am not experienced with xcode. Can anyone pls help me?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably trying to build for a simulator:

[image]

instead of for a device:

[image]

Switch the simulator to a device, and the Archive option should become available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select 'iOS Device' target scheme, not simulator. See below image:

[image]